# Trouble adding a DataTemplateSelector to a wpf XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, datatemplate

This is my first time ever doing anything with XAML and I'm a bit lost.

I'm trying to add a DataTemplateSelector to my XAML page using the instructions found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).
However I'm stuck on the part where I'm supposed to "declare the TaskListDataTemplateSelector as a resource". This is the example given:

```
<Window.Resources>
     ...
     <local:TaskListDataTemplateSelector x:Key="myDataTemplateSelector"/>
     ...
</Window.Resources>
```

However, the top level tag in the XAML document is `<UserControl>`, and I don't see anything about `Window` or `Window.Resources`.

Under the `<UserControl>` tag is a `<UserControl.Resources>` tag, but when I try to put the example code there, it gives me an error saying "The namespace prefix 'local' is not defined". I tried replacing "local" with the actual namespace, but got the same error.

The custom DataTemplateSelector class is in the codebehind for the XAML page, and is in the same namespace.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who googled this question like I did:

I think I found the answer.

You need to define the local prefix in your XAML file.
This can be done by placing the following namespace argument in the root element:

```
   xmlns:local="clr-namespace:AssemblyName"
```

Change "AssemblyName" in your erm.. assembly's name.